# prompting user to input in query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from Attendant where Attendant_id= **&**Attendant_id;
```

Why don't this work in SQL server,
Is there another way of doing this in SQL server

Comment: What is `**&**Attendant_id` ? What are you trying to do here? Sql Server is a database engine, it can't prompt for anything. Do you mean you have an application that you want to execute a query with user supplied input?

Comment: I tried this in oracle 11g, it worked there,
What this query usually does is that it displays all the data of the particular attendant id that the user will enter, in oracle 11g 
when this query is written then oracle asks for the user to enter an attendant id so that it could display the relative columns of that specific row

Comment: Oracle is not the same as Sql Server. Also Oracle is also a RDMS but perhaps you were using a query tool to access it. What tool are you using to query sql server?

Comment: iam using sql server management studio

Comment: That is not an option is SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Attendant WHERE Attendant_id LIKE  = '%Attendant_id%';
```

This statement selects all strings that contain "Attendant_id" in any position.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) is not like Oracle Sql Developer.  Oracle Sql Developer will throw up prompts for :variable values.

You must provide a value IN YOUR CODE.

```
Declare @SSN varchar(11) = '222-22-2222'
SELECT * from dbo.Employee emp where emp.Ssn = @SSN
```